# convert excel worksheet to sql script

Tags: sql, excel

I have a excel worksheet (.xls). I need to convert it into sql script. The single excel worksheet consists of multiple tables. So the resultant script should have multiple create table and insert statements. 
I tried various tools such as [http://www.sqlconverter.com/](http://excel2sql.esy.es/) but I am unable to get a proper solution. Any other way I can do it?

Comment: AFAIK MS SQL Server provides some functions to load excel sheets into a database: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686

Comment: i saw this link before but its quite complicated and i am unable to get through it.. i need a simple solution for it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I noticed your comment that using the import wizard was more complicated of a solution than you wanted, so you must be trying to load data.

You can try `BULK INSERT`:

First, do a SAVE AS on each sheet and convert them to CSV files.  You should have one CSV file for each sheet you want to import.

Next, make a table with the similar data types and length that you'll be bringing in.  A typical Excel cell is a VARCHAR(255), (probably more like NVARCHAR(255) if you want to be specific, but we'll avoid unicode for this solution).

So, if your excel sheet had 5 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Sheet1
(Column1 VARCHAR(255)
, Column2 VARCHAR(255)
, Column3 VARCHAR(255)
, Column4 VARCHAR(255)
, Column5 VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Then you can write a simple bulk insert to the table PROVIDED you have the file on network share or local the to server/machine where the SQL instance is.  For example, if you had the file on your machine and wanted to try and push to a server out on the network, SQL would think the `C:\` in the script below was on the server and not your machine.   You would have to share a folder and access it over the network: `\\MyMachineName\SharedFolder\Sheet1.csv`

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Sheet1
FROM 'C:\LocalFolder\WhereTheFileIs\Sheet1.csv'
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

This should get the data into that table provided the same number of columns exist in the file and table.

It's not pretty, but it's simple.  The `BULK INSERT` is a tried and true method of basic and quick loading.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple method to group insert from Excell: simply if your data is in columns B,C  and D in sepearate column create formula:
    ="insert into  values('" &B1 &"','" & C1 & "','"&D1&"')

Answer (score 0):

this is created by vamsi krishna mysore
1.apache apoi should be used it should be added to the files and system
apache apoi i sused in this project

```
  package excelread;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import jxl.Cell;
    import jxl.Sheet;
    import jxl.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.UnderlinePatterns;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

    public class ExcelRead 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
           try
        {
            FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
      FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("result.sql");//sql script in the script
      FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("result.xlxs");
    FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("result.csv");
            XWPFDocument doc=new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFParagraph para=doc.createParagraph();
            para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            XWPFRun pararun=para.createRun();
            pararun.setBold(true);
            pararun.setFontSize(20);
            pararun.setText("Database Tables\n\n");
            File f= new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\BUILDING_TB.xls");//file location where it is stored in the system
            Workbook wb= Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
            int sheets=wb.getNumberOfSheets();
            for(int s1=0;s1<sheets;s1++)
            {
                   System.out.println("for sheet"+s1);
                   Sheet s= wb.getSheet(s1);
                   String tbname=s.getName();
                   XWPFParagraph para1=doc.createParagraph();
                   para1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
                   pararun=para1.createRun();
                   pararun.setText(tbname);
                   pararun.setFontSize(16);
                   pararun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.WORDS);
                   int rows=s.getRows();
                   int cols=s.getColumns();
                   int indexrows=0;
                   int cols1=0;
                   int indexcols=0;
                   int pk=1000,dt=1000,cn=1000,ci=1000,dd=1000,n=1000,com=1000;
                   int ava=0;
                   List <String> comments= new LinkedList <String>();
                   List <String> sequence= new LinkedList <String>();
                   List <String> cid= new LinkedList <String>();
                   String createQuery="create table " +tbname+"(";
                   System.out.println(rows+" "+cols);
                    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)     //TO AVOID EMPTY ROW AND COLUMNS
                    {
                    sequence.clear();
                    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)     //TO GET ONE ROW DETAILS
                    {
                    indexcols=0;
                    cols1=0;
                    Cell c=s.getCell(i,j);
                    sequence.add(c.getContents());
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
                    {
                        if(sequence.get(i)=="")
                        {
                            cols1= ++indexcols;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ava=1;
                            indexrows=j;
                            break;
                        }  
                    }
                    if(ava==1)
                       break;
                    }
            for(;indexcols<cols;indexcols++)        //TO ARRANG DATA IN REQUIRED ORDER
            {
                    if(sequence.get(indexcols).toLowerCase().contains("PK".toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        pk=indexcols;   
                    }
                    else if(sequence.get(indexcols).toLowerCase().contains("Column_id".toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        ci=indexcols;
                    }
                    else if(sequence.get(indexcols).toLowerCase().contains("Column_Name".toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        cn=indexcols;
                    }
                    else if(sequence.get(indexcols).toLowerCase().contains("nullable".toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        n=indexcols;
                    }
                    else if(sequence.get(indexcols).toLowerCase().contains("Data_TYpe".toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        dt=indexcols;
                    }
                    else if(sequence.get(indexcols).toLowerCase().contains("Default".toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        dd=indexcols;
                    }
                    else if(sequence.get(indexcols).toLowerCase().contains("comments".toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        com=indexcols;    
                    }
            }
            indexrows++;
            int rows1=indexrows;
            for(;indexrows<rows;indexrows++)        //PREPARING QUERY(For excel rows which contain data)
            {
                       indexcols=cols1;
                         for(;indexcols<cols;indexcols++)   //for all columns
                         {

                            Cell c=s.getCell(indexcols, indexrows);
                            String item=c.getContents();
                            //adding Column name to query
                              if(indexcols==cn)
                               {   if(!(item.equals("")) &&  indexrows!=rows1)   
                                   createQuery =createQuery+" ,"+item;
                                    else if(item.equals(""))
                                    break;
                                    else
                                    createQuery =createQuery+" "+item;
                                }
                              //adding data type to query
                                 if(indexcols==dt)
                                    {
                                        createQuery =createQuery+" "+item;
                                    }
                            //adding data default to query
                                   else if(indexcols==dd)
                                    {    
                                        if(item=="")
                                        continue;
                                        else
                                        createQuery =createQuery+" "+"default "+item;
                                    }
                                //addig primary key constaint to query
                                    else if(indexcols==pk)
                                      {
                                        if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                                        createQuery =createQuery+" "+"primary key";
                                        else
                                        createQuery =createQuery+" "+"";
                                      }
                                //adding not null constraint to query
                                    else if(indexcols==n)
                                    {
                                        if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                                        createQuery =createQuery+" "+"not null";
                                        else
                                        createQuery =createQuery+" "+"";
                                    }
                                    //adding comments
                                    else if(indexcols==com)
                                        {
                                            if(item!="")
                                            {
                                            comments.add(item);
                                            }
                                            else 
                                            {
                                            comments.add("comments empty");
                                            }
                                        }   
                                      else if(indexcols==ci)
                                        {
                                            if(item!=null)
                                            {
                                            cid.add(item);
                                            }

                                        }

                          }//column loop close
                 }//row looop close
                        createQuery=createQuery+")";
                        System.out.println(createQuery);
                        XWPFParagraph para2=doc.createParagraph();
                        para2.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
                        pararun=para2.createRun();
                        pararun.setFontSize(14);
                        pararun.setText(createQuery+";");
                        System.out.println("table created successfully");
                       }//sheets loop closse

            doc.write(output);  //writing data into ouptu file
            output.close();
         }//try block close
         catch(Exception e)
            {
                 System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

         }//main close
       }//class close
```