# Need help starting simple MySQL database using data from Excel

Tags: mysql, database, excel

I'm and intern and I've been tasked with something I'm pretty unfamiliar with. My manager has requested I create a simple MySQL database using data from an Excel file(s) and I have no idea where to start. I would normally ask someone here for help but everyone seems to be really busy. Basically, the purpose of the database is to see what different object-groups relate to one another so as to keep things standardized. Trying not to go into detail about things not really relevant.

I was asked to first design a schema for the database and then I would get an update on how to implement it. Would I just start by writing queries to create tables? I'm assuming I would need to convert the Excel files to .csv, how do I read this data and send it to the correct table based on Object Type (an attribute of each object, represented in a column)?

I don't want to ask too much right now, but if someone could help me understand what I need to do to get started I would really appreciate it.

Comment: look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067370/convert-excel-worksheet-to-sql-script

Comment: You'll also want to read up on [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the column headers in your spread sheet.
2. Decide which columns relate to Objects and which columns relate to Groups
3. The columns that relate to just Objects will become your field names for the Object table. Give this table an ID field so you can uniquely identify each Object.
4. The columns that relate to the Groups will become field names for a Group table. Give this table an ID field so you can uniquely identify each Group.
5. Think about if an Object can be in more than one Group - if so you will probably need an Object-Group table. This table would most likely contain an ObjectID and a GroupID.